# c# using and vb.net imports suggestions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am starting to code in c# because i now prefer it over vb.net. One thing that is is a bit funny to me, and maybe its a setting or something, but vb.net (vs 2010 or vs 2013) if you type in code (c#) and you are missing a reference, vb.net suggests which reference you may need to import, and will import it for you if you say so.

c# however just says (not exact wording) you missing a reference. Is there a setting or something that i can change in order to get c# to work like vb.net in this case

Comment: Are you talking about missing references or missing imports/usings?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a refernce to the assembly containing the type visual studio cannot really do anything to help.  If however you have a reference, after typing the type name either right click on it or drop down the context menu with the menu key, go to the "Resolve" item, and in the sub menu will be options for adding a using statement or changing the type name to the fully qualified type name with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

That is not language issue at all, but `IDE` issue that handles that language.

If you are using `Visual Studio` recent versions, it's enoutgh to click on the type and on the left bottom appears a small line, if you hover it appears a window with suggessions of possible namespaces to define.

Or simply click on the type and presss `CTRL+SHIFT+F10` (you may have different keys setup on your machine) and it will do the same.